# Show that $\int_{C} \frac{e^{az}}{\sin(\pi z)} \,dz \rightarrow 0 \quad as \quad R \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Given the straight line in the complex plane: $b+iR$ to $b+1+iR$ where $0<b<1$ and $|Im(a)|<\pi$, show the following:

$$\int_{C} \frac{e^{az}}{\sin(\pi z)} \,dz \rightarrow 0 \quad as \quad R \rightarrow \infty$$

I proceed by bounding the integral with $z=b+x+iR \quad ; \quad 0\leq x \leq 1$

$$\bigg|\int_{C} \frac{e^{az}}{\sin(\pi z)} \,dz\bigg|=\int_{b}^{b+1} \frac{|e^{a(b+x+iR)}|}{|\sin(\pi (b+x+iR))|} \,|dx| \leq  \frac{2e^{ab}}{e^{-R}-e^{R}}$$

However, the last expression derived does not approach $0$, and I am unsure where I am going wrong -advice?

Edit: Just realized my process was indeed correct, and that the expression does tend to $0$.

Comment: side note; \oint implies a closed contour.

Comment: Typo - thanks for the tip.

Comment: note that your last bound contains $x$, yet the left-hand side (after the integration), does not. Also, note that your last term looks like $1/e^R$ which does go to $0$ for very big $R$.

Comment: @Chip I removed the x in the last expression, and you're right...brain fart I suppose. Thanks for your help!

Comment: welcome @Jay. we are all on this website for similar reasons.